# Graphing complex equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I'm trying to self-study ordinary differential equations from this introductory book by Earl A. Coddington. There's a preliminaries section which goes over complex numbers and I'm having trouble solving the following equation: $$\left|z-1\right|+\left|z+2\right|=8,\;z\in\Bbb{C}$$

The book asks to graphically represent it, and I got this far: $$\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}=8$$

I don't really have a good idea for getting rid of the radicals. A vanishing thought was multiplying both sides by the "conjugate" of the LHS (i.e. $\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}-\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}$ ) and substituting some variables to turn it into a quadratic equation:
$$(x-1)^2+y^2-(x+2)^2+y^2=8\left[\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}-\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}\right]$$
$$u^2-v^2=8(u-v)$$
where $u=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}$ and $v=\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}$.

I found this line to be intractable. I consulted Wolfram Alpha and it said it was supposed to be an ellipse. I would really appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Edit (1): Following Raffaele's suggestion, I got: $$\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}=8-\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}$$ $$(x-1)^2+y^2=64-16\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}+(x+2)^2+y^2$$ $$6x+67=16\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}$$ $$(6x+67)^2=256\left[(x+2)^2+y^2\right]$$
$$\frac{55}{256}(7-2x)(2x+9)=y^2$$
$$\frac{55}{4}-\frac{55}{256}(2x-1)^2=y^2$$
$$\frac{4y^2}{55}+\frac{4(2x+1)^2}{256}=1$$
I'm fairly confident with the algebra; I checked it against Wolfram Alpha, but I don't feel as though I gained anything from solving this problem. Was there a concept I missed? If the module is constant like Raffaele said, shouldn't the plot be a circle?

Edit (2): I think I see what I misunderstood: the sum of the distances between z and two points is constant, so the shape should be an ellipse.

Comment: move 1 radical to LHS, then square, then move all terms in one side and leave only 1 radical in the other and square again. Anyway the module function means the distance between two complex numbers and here the sum of the distance of $z$ from two fixed points is constant. Do this fact recall something in the analytic geometry you have studied?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I haven't studied analytic geometry. I've seen the word module thrown around when I was trying to look for help on this problem, but I didn't know what it meant. Would that imply it's a circle then?

Comment: Why not try easier$ | z+3|+ |z-3|=10? $

Comment: @JellyHops In the complex plane the modulus $|a-b|$ is the distance between points $a$ and $b$. Therefore the equation $\left|z-1\right|+\left|z+2\right|=8$ says that the sum of distances from $z$ to the fixed points $1$ and $-2$ (both on the real axis) is a constant $8$. It follows that the locus of $z$ is an [ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse) with foci $1,-2$.

Comment: @JellyHops No,  It's the definition of an ellipse

Comment: Thank you. I read it too quickly the first time. I already made the correction in the post.